# SQLite Database is not open Error

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a constructor that takes data from a SQL Server database and puts it in a local SQLite database:

```
public ForemanController()
        {
            connectionString.DataSource = "dxdb02v";
            connectionString.InitialCatalog = "QTRAX4619410";
            connectionString.UserID = "tunnelld";
            connectionString.Password = "david";

            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [QTRAXAdmin].[vwQT_Foreman]";

            List<Foreman> list;
            // Creates a SQL connection
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        list = new List<Foreman>();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            list.Add(new Foreman { ForeBadge = reader.GetString(0), ForeName = reader.GetString(1) });
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
                allForeman = list.ToArray();
            }
            string deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM Foreman;";
            using (SQLiteConnection SQLconn1 = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnectionString))
            {
                using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(deleteSQL, SQLconn1))
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            using (SQLiteConnection SQLconn2 = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnectionString))
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd2 = SQLconn2.CreateCommand();
                foreach (Foreman row in allForeman)
                {
                    cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Foreman (ForeBadge, ForeName) VALUES (@param1, @param2);";
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", row.ForeBadge));
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param2", row.ForeName));
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Everything seems to be working fine until the last using statement:

```
            using (SQLiteConnection SQLconn2 = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnectionString))
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd2 = SQLconn2.CreateCommand();
                foreach (Foreman row in allForeman)
                {
                    cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Foreman (ForeBadge, ForeName) VALUES (@param1, @param2);";
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", row.ForeBadge));
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param2", row.ForeName));
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Its pretty evident, you don't open it like you do the others. You need a `SQLconn2.Open()` or `cmd2.Connection.Open()` somewhere.

Comment: missing `SQLConn2.Open();`

Comment: Side note - that's WAY too much to be doing in a class constructor.  I would seriously reconsider making it a separate method (or set of methods).  Constructors should be light and should not throw any exceptions (since they are harder to debug)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because that's the only place you forgot to open the connection.

add this: `SQLconn2.Open();`

Comment: It may be obvious but why don't I need to open the connection for the DELETE statement?

Comment: You DO open it for the DELETE statement: `command.Connection.Open();`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to open the connection.

```
SQLConn2.Open();
```